# Function by recursion on a set $X$ satisfy Peano's axioms

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, set-theory, recursion, peano-axioms

I've been stuck on this theorem for like two days and I still don't really get it.
I'm reading the construction of natural numbers using "classic set theory for guided independent study", and it says:

"To construct arithmetic operations a key tool will be the definition of a function $f$ by recursion. In the context of a set $X$ satisfying Peano's axioms, this means giving $0$ some value and explaining how to define $f(S(x))$ assuming one knew the value of $f(x)$"

then it gives this example:

"define $f$ on $\{0, 1, 2, \cdots\}$ by $f(0)=1$ and $f(n+1)=(n+1)f(n)$ for $n>0$ then to workout $f(m)$ for some specific $m$, use the second part of the definition until you hit $f(0)$, for instance: $f(3)=f(2+1)=3f(2)=3f(1+1)=3·2f(1)=6f(0+1)=6·1f(0)=6·1=6$
infact this $f$ is just the factorial function $f(n)=n!$"

I understand all this but this is the part I don't really get:

"A general result about defining a function by recursion on a set $X$ satisfying Peano's axioms is as follows: Let $X$ satisfy Peano's axioms. Let $Y$ be any set, $y_0$ any element of $Y$ and $h:X×Y→Y$ a function on pairs $(x,y)∈X×Y$. Then there exists a unique function $f:X→Y$ such that $f(0)=y_0$ and $f(S(x))=h(x,f(x))$ for all $x$."

I don't really understand this part, I understand what it states but I don't understand what it's trying to convey. Peano's axioms that this book is talking about are:

"A Peano system is a set $X$ with a special element $0\in X$ and a funtion $S:X\to X$ such that the following also hold:

1. The function $S$ is one-one
2. For all $x\in X$, $0\neq S(x)$
3. For all subset $A\subseteq X$, if $A$ contains $0$ and contains $S(x)$ whenever $x\in A$, then $A$ is all of $X$."

After that theorem it also says:

"for the example above we could take both $X$ and $Y$ to be the set of natural numbers, $y_0=1$ and $h$ the function $h(x,y)=(x+1)\cdot y$

What is the function $S$ in that example? What is $h$? Why is $h$ defined like $h(x,y)=(x+1)·y$? I don't really understand, could you guys help me out please?

Comment: See [Recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem)

Comment: Can you post who is that book by?

Comment: @PrimeMover D.C. Goldrei https://www.amazon.com/Classic-Set-Theory-Independent-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B075FCTRKP/ref=sr_1_1?crid=24QP51KQ61X1F&dchild=1&keywords=classic+set+theory+for+guided+independent+study&qid=1594201650&sprefix=set+theory+independe%2Caps%2C281&sr=8-1

Comment: That $S$ is in fact the "successor mapping": $S(x) = x + 1$ in the context of natural numbers. It is defined like this because when you are first defining the Peano set, you have not got $+$ defined yet. The exercise then is to *deduce* the properties of $\mathbb N$ purely by making deductions from those simple axioms.

Comment: Further info: there is a page on this on ProofWiki: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom:Peano%27s_Axioms which might help if you work through it

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but how do you know that $f(1)=h(0,f(0))$ if you don't know $S(x)$?

Comment: No, no... Of course $S(x)$ is the *successor* function; " Let $X$ satisfy Peano's axioms..." this means that we have $0 \in X$ and $S : X \to X$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so $f(S(x))$ is $f(1)$ because you set $x=0$ and $S(0)=0+1=1$ since it's the successor function? but at the same time how you know that that is the successor function and not some other function if in the definition of Peano's axiom they just gave some properties of $S$ and they didn't explicitely say that it's the successor function? What if it's another one? could you help me out please this book sucks it's making me crazy everyday lol..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitions by recursion are typical of natural numbers (in set theory, they can be generalized); see [Recursion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem)).

This kind of definition exploits the key facts about $\mathbb N$ as defined by [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms):

> $0, S(x)$ and Induction axiom.

Consider the following example regarding the function $a^n$.

For every real number $a$ we define $a^n$ recursively as follows:

> $a^0=1$ and $a^{n+1}=a^n \cdot a$, for every $n \in \mathbb N$.

How can formalize the above definition with recursion formalism?

Let assume $a \in \mathbb R$ and let $f: \mathbb N \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

We have: $f(0,a)=1$, and we have:

> $f(S(n), a)= f(n,a) \cdot a$.

Here the "auxiliary" function $h(x,y)$ is simply the *product*, i.e.

> $\cdot: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

---

The definition provides a simple procedure (an algorithm) to compute $a^n$ for every $n$; this facts is based on the Induction axiom that guarantees that we can reach every natural number $n$ after a finite number of steps.

We start with $n=0$ and we compute $a^0=1$, using the first part of the definition.

Having $a^0$, i.e. $f(0,a)$, we use it in the second part of the defintioin to compute:

> $a^1=f(1,a)=f(S(0),a)=h(f(0),a)=h(1,a)=1 \cdot a=a$.

*And so on*... (this is Induction).

Comment: thank you!! i finally get it

Comment: @cekami7844 - you are welcome :-)

Comment: in the definition of the book though, what is h(x, f(x)) (or $h(n,f(n))$) if the function being defined is $f(n)=n!=n(n-1)(n-2)...$ and $f(0)=1$? i have $S(n)=n$, and therefore $f(S(n))=f(n)$ but then what? the book says $h(x, y)=(x+1)y$ but how?

Comment: for example, if $n=3$, $f(n)=3!=6$, in this case $h(n, f(n))$ would be $h(n, f(n))=(n+1)f(n)=4(6)=24$ what is this 24??

Comment: @cekami7844 - what does it mean "what is this 24" ? In [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Formulation) *numerals* (i.e. "name" for numbers) are defined through $S(x)$: $1= S(0), 2=S(1)=S(S(0)), \ldots$.

Comment: i dont understand what $h(x,y)$ is in the example with $n!$, now i'm noticing in your example that you definied $f:N×R→R$ in the same way the book defined $h(x,y)$ so why you said that $h(x,y)$ is the product?

Comment: @cekami7844 - Yes; as you have written $(n+1)!=f(S(n))=h(S(n),f(n))=S(n) \cdot f(n)=(n+1) \cdot n!$ and thus $h$ is product.

Comment: yeah i'm sorry i understand.. i dont know why this is so complicated for me, do you have any advice on "how to learn better/faster"? i only know some calculus, linear algebra and some logic, but i think i'm not good at all (compared to mathematicians, teachers etc), you have any advice for studying alone without a teacher?

Comment: @cekami7844 - ["no royal road"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Euclid#Attributed) :-( Some good textbook on logic and abstract mat: E.Mendelson, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic (6th ed 2015)](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), H.Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic (2nd ed. 2001)](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&printsec=frontcover), D.van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZWbsCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), P.Suppes, [Axiomatic ST](https://books.google.it/books?id=skTCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: R.Smullyan, [First-order Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=kgvhQ-oSZiUC&printsec=frontcover), E.Bloch, [The Real Numbers and Real Analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=r0qcU9U2_I4C&printsec=frontcover)